# Magento multisite form submittin get cleared in end point action

Tags: magento, post

I have a magento site with following domains.

> **http://www.site.eu/**
>
>      http://www.site.it/
>      http://www.site.es/
>      http://www.site.fr/
>      http://www.site.de/
>   **http://www.site.co.uk/**
>
>   **http://www.site.com/**

I am trying to submit the email address for newsletter subscription. (Magento has this).

*Following is showing newsletter subscription form's code*

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
    <div class="form-subscribe">
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Go') ?>" class="button"><span>  <span><?php echo $this->__('Go') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

`echo $this->getFormActionUrl()` generate the action url with the https on it.

example:

following sites will have URL called **https://www.site.eu/newsletter/subscriber/new/**  Because Configuration I set base secure url as https://www.site.eu/

> http://www.site.it/
>      http://www.site.es/
>      http://www.site.fr/
>      http://www.site.de/

Other sites will redirect to https with their own domain. These will work properly
http://www.site.com/   Redirect to https://www.site.com/
http://www.site.co.uk/ Redirect to https://www.site.co.uk/

If user click submit button within any of above site then the site will navigate to https://www.site.eu/newsletter/subscriber/new/ but without having any post data. So according to the situation I cannot access POST variables (email)

I believe I have explained the the problem properly. Please advice why is this happening? Any solutions come to your mind?

Comment: If you have your site.eu domain as a forward in the DNS then it may be stripping that data out when it redirects.  If you want all of the form submits to go to site.eu, have you tried just hardcoding that in the form action?  Open that template and change `action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>"` to `action="https://www.site.eu/newsletter/subscriber/new/"`.  That way it's not hitting the other domains first before redirecting.

Comment: Thanks but it's Not working. After submit the form even though if its hard coded variables cleared in the subscriber new action.

Comment: Are you using IE to test this? What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is, you cannot post data from http to https? or on backend try use both secure & unsecure url with https